# Ashot screenshot does not correctly crop the element from screenshot

Tags: java, selenium, ashot, visual-testing

I am trying to open [this url](https://www.immoweb.be/en/search/house/for-sale?countries=BE&page=1&orderBy=relevance) and take the screenshot of the **Keep browsing** button which looks like the below image using [Ashot library](https://github.com/pazone/ashot).

[image]

Here is my dependencies on pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.ashot</groupId>
      <artifactId>ashot</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

And here is my code:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium-driver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    String baseUrl = "https://www.immoweb.be/en/search/house/for-sale?countries=BE&page=1&orderBy=relevance";
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    Thread.sleep(3000);


    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='uc-btn-accept-banner']"));
    Screenshot screenshot = new AShot().coordsProvider(new WebDriverCoordsProvider())
        .takeScreenshot(driver, element);

    File actualFile = new File("C:\\baseImage\\dashboardActual.png");
    ImageIO.write(screenshot.getImage(), "png", actualFile);

    driver.close();

 
  }
}
```

But when i executes the code, the taken screenshot not correct.

Here is my screenshot:

[image]

Update: After reading this question, i added the shootingStartegy which also was not helpful:

```
Screenshot screenshot =
    new AShot()
        .shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(100))
        .coordsProvider(new WebDriverCoordsProvider())
        .takeScreenshot(driver, element);
```

Comment: What if you do the screenshot of entire page or screenshot elements of what nest the button you need? Are they rendered properly?

Comment: Actually, i need to figure out how to take screenshot of any element. Therefore, the screenshot of whole page is not useful for me. I just suggested the button for the simplicity. it can be any arbitrary element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, AShot library doesn't have enough documentation. However, you do not need AShot to take screenshot of an element but you need it for making a comparision between two different images. Here is my suggested solution:

```
  public static String URL = "https://www.immoweb.be/en/search/house/for-sale?countries=BE&page=1&orderBy=relevance";
  // Notice that the ELEMENT_ID  might change as the website is dynamic
  public static String ELEMENT_ID = "//article[@id='classified_9408324']";
  public static String BUTTON_ID =  "//*[@id='uc-btn-accept-banner']";
  public static int DELAY_IN_MILLI_SECONDS = 5000;

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium-driver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    
    driver.get(URL);
    Thread.sleep(DELAY_IN_MILLI_SECONDS);
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(BUTTON_ID)).click();
    
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(ELEMENT_ID));
    
    File actualFile = element.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    BufferedImage  actualImage = ImageIO.read(actualFile);
    FileUtils.copyFile(actualFile, new File("C:\\baseImage\\dashboardActual.png"));
    
    File expectedFile = new File("C:\\baseImage\\6.png");
    BufferedImage  expectedImage = ImageIO.read(expectedFile);
    
    // Compare two images for visual testing
    ImageDiff diff = new ImageDiffer().makeDiff(actualImage, expectedImage);
    BufferedImage diffImage = diff.getMarkedImage();
    
    File diffFile = new File("C:\\baseImage\\Diff.png");
    ImageIO.write(diffImage, "jpg", diffFile);
    
    Assert.assertFalse("Images are not equal",diff.hasDiff());
    
    driver.close();
```

So, to make it short, the following line, which works by Selenium, can take the screenshot of element and you can use it as the Base-Image for your visual testing:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(ELEMENT_ID));

File actualFile = element.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
BufferedImage  actualImage = ImageIO.read(actualFile);
FileUtils.copyFile(actualFile, new File("C:\\baseImage\\dashboardActual.png"));
```

And here is the image:

[image]